Firebase cloud messaging web issues in Safari 17.4
I've been using Firebase messaging web (javascript) on macos/ios Safari since 16.4 and everything worked well, but now i noticed issues with firebase messaging registration (no changes made to my code) on safari 17.4. It seems firebase requests to https://fcmregistrations.googleapis.com/ are failing with 400 Bad Request. I tested so far in in Safari 17.4.1 MacOS Ventura 13.6.6 (22G630), multiple systems. I also tried updating firebase to latest version 10.10.0:
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.10.0/firebase-app-compat.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.10.0/firebase-messaging-compat.js');
Specifically, requests to "https://fcmregistrations.googleapis.com/v1/projects/.../registrations/" seem to have missing data in the payload:
{"web":{"endpoint":"","auth":"","p256dh":"","applicationPubKey": "......LMbu5N....."}};

For example, in Chrome, the endpoint, p256dh and auth properties have non-empty values (something similar to values: "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/dKxAeok......", "BFDONgo....", and "2stao....." respectively)
Everything works well on chrome and firefox, latest versions, and also it worked well on Safari 17.3. If someone managed to find a solution for this, please let me know.
EDIT:
Same behavior for Safari 17.5

It doesn't work for me either. The problem is discussed here, here and in other places. No solution on the horizon - scary.
